# When using puppet with vagrant, is it necessary after the first vagrant up to run the next vagrant up with --no-provision?

Tags: linux, vagrant, puppet, provisioning

I kept running into a problem with my puppet development environment in Vagrant which would bring up more than one VirtualBox Virtual Machine.

I use the shell provisioner to install puppet on the puppet master and the puppet client and this is run during the first `vargrant up`, I then allow each machine to see the others using /etc/hosts via the `vagrant hostsupdater` plugin.

Then I run `sudo puppet apply site.pp` on the Puppet Server; and run `sudo puppet agent --server puppet-server --verbose --no-daemonize --waitforcert 10 --noop` on the puppet client.

Then when the certificate shows up on the puppet server in the `sudo puppet cert list`, I sign the cert with `sudo puppet cert <client-host-name>`, the cert gets cached on the client;

Back on the client I run `sudo puppet agent --server puppet-server --verbose --no-daemonize --waitforcert 10`, and note that the changes are made to that machine.

Now the next thing I did was shutdown all of the machines using `sudo shutdown -h now`

And then previously when I would bring them back online with `vagrant up` the connection between the two would stop working, puppet citing some error about the certificates not matching.

But recently when I tried these steps again, I took a different way of doing it, instead of running `vagrant up` I ran `vagrant up --no-provision` second time the machines booted up, and it appears that the two can again communicate.

My theory is that the reason for this is that when the machines are re-provisioned the second time they are booted up excluding the `--no-provision` parameter the CA is re-generated, and thus it causes an issue because the two machines no longer have each others certificates.

Is this correct?  It's been really annoying having to re-create the machines and setup puppet manually all the time.

Also is it possible for my vagrant SHELL provisioner to check if puppet has already been installed to automatically skip the re-installation of puppet if it is already installed?

Additionally, is there a way to automatically run the `sudo puppet apply site.pp` on the Puppet Server after installation and run `sudo puppet agent --server puppet-server --verbose --no-daemonize --waitforcert 10 --noop` on the puppet client, and back to the server to add the certificate, in the correct order using the shell provisioner?

P.S. Yes, I already know there is a puppet provisioner for vagrant, but I'm learning the client/server end of puppet.

Comment: I'm just trying to verify that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

hum, this is strange.

The only reason a provisioner will run on a second (and upcoming) `vagrant up` is that you specifically ask for it so if you have something like

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "blablabla", :run => 'always'
```

notice the `:run => always` this is telling vagrant to run the provisioner. The output of `vagrant up` (without any option) will be

```
==> app: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> app: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
==> app: Running provisioner: shell...
```

Comment: So that isn't it?  Maybe `:run => 'always'` is the default?

Comment: nop always is not the default - can you display the output of `vagrant up` like I did to see it vagrant says _Machine already provisioned_